# Is there any research into the effectiveness of the "Zettelkasten" (slip box) method of processing notes?

Tags: learning

In the book "How to take smart notes: one simple technique to boost writing, learning and thinking: for students, academics and nonfiction book writers" by Söhnke Arens the author makes the claim that using the "Zettelkasten" method for organizing notes is highly effective. To support this argument the author points to Niklas Luhmann who was a very productive social scientist in the 20th century and used the method. However the author does not actually cite any research that proves that the system works for everyone. Is there actually any research? If not, is there any consensus on which system students should use to organize their knowledge?

Edit: Here is Luhmann himself explaining his system.
http://luhmann.surge.sh/communicating-with-slip-boxes